# Loading Spinner Style for Cordova Android

Tags: android, cordova, spinner, progressdialog

I am developing an Android application in Cordova using the [InAppbrowser plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/pull/88/files). There are a default load spinner and progress dialog. But I want to change the spinner style. In the link you will find the source of plugin and changed code for spinner. Is there anything I can do to change the spinner icon style programmatically?

Comment: Check this link: https://github.com/roberthovhannisyan/PhoneGap-Plugin-ListPicker. It may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

My open source library [**BlackTie.js**](https://www.github.com/divakarmanivel/blacktie) has a `showLoading` function that does exactly what you need!